# Javascript conditional syntax, condensing multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, syntax, conditional-statements

I have the following code. I feel like I'm being redundant but don't know how to condense these statements into one.

What's the right syntax / most efficient + readable way to write multiple conditional statements like this?

```
        if(coorx < 440 && n < 4) {
            continue;
        }

        if(coorx < 280 && n < 5) {
            continue;
        }           

        if(coorx < 180 && n < 6) {
            continue;
        }
```

Comment: If there is a consistent pattern you may be able to create a single expression that covers all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the same code is executed regardless of which `if` statement is executed, you can condense all those conditions into one `if` conditional using the Javascript OR operator (`||`):

```
if ((coorx < 440 && n < 4)  || (coorx < 280 && n < 5) || (coorx < 280 && n < 5))
    continue;
```

Comment: You can omit the parentheses for these particular conditions (though obviously not for _all_ conditions).

Comment: @nnnnnn - Perhaps, but I still think they're best to leave in for readability purposes. I edited out the text which made them seem required, though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply split the conditions with OR. AND has a higher priority, so the following works:

```
if(coorx < 440 && n < 4 || coorx < 280 && n < 5 || coorx < 180 && n < 6) 
    continue;
```

Comment: Put in parentheses.  Maybe *you* remember the precedence rules correctly, but the next guy might not!

Answer (score 0):

Like @jeff said, but making intelligent use of whitespace so line length doesn't get out of control (and for easiest readability):

```
if (

  ( coorx < 440 && n < 4 ) ||

  ( coorx < 280 && n < 5 ) ||

  ( coorx < 180 && n < 6 )

) {

  continue;

}
```